# How to get the current path, using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I need to get the `location.pathname` and compare it to the links to determine if the clicked anchor/sidebar item should be set to active or not (will become a red button if clicked). The topics should be active first, the user gets there from login page.

The problem is, I cannot get the location pathname of the current page. If I switch to another component of the sidebar, it logs the previous path, which makes it impossible to work with, in my case.

```
export const SideBar = ({ isSidebarOpen }) => {
  const [IsActive, setIsActive] = useState("topics");
  const location = useLocation().pathname;

  const toggleActiveSideNavbarItem = (id) => {
    console.log(location);
    console.log(id);
    setIsActive(id);
  };

  const anchors = [
    {
      id: "topics",
      icon: <InfoCircleFill />,
      text: "topics",
      link: "",
    },
    {
      id: "employees",
      icon: <PersonLinesFill />,
      text: "employees",
      link: "employees",
    },
    {
      id: "dashboard",
      icon: <BarChartFill />,
      text: "dashboard",
      link: "dashboard",
    },
    {
      id: "user-entry",
      icon: <PersonPlusFill />,
      text: "user",
      link: "user",
    },
  ];

  return (
    <nav>
        {anchors.map((anchor) => (
          <Link
            to={anchor.link}
            key={anchor.id}
            className={`list-group-item border-0 d-inline-block text-truncate mb-3 ${anchor.id === IsActive ? "active" : ""} `}
            onClick={() => toggleActiveSideNavbarItem(anchor.id)}
            data-bs-parent="#sidebar"
          >
            {anchor.icon}
              <span className="ms-2">{anchor.text}</span>
          </Link>
          ))}
      <>
        <Outlet />
      </>
   </nav>
  );
};
```

Any ideas?

When I use `useEffect`, the location `pathname` is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage the `className` attribute based on `location.pathname` directly, you don't really need a state for that.
 You can determine the active one  by comparing its link property to the current `location.pathname`

```js
export const SideBar = ({ isSidebarOpen }) => {
  const location = useLocation().pathname;

  const anchors = [
      // ...
  ];

  return (
    <nav>
      {anchors.map((anchor) => (
        <Link
          to={anchor.link}
          key={anchor.id}
          className={`list-group-item border-0 d-inline-block text-truncate mb-3 ${anchor.link === location ? "active" : ""} `}
          data-bs-parent="#sidebar"
        >
          {anchor.icon}
          <span className="ms-2">{anchor.text}</span>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

React-Router-Dom already knows what the active route is, no need to reinvent the wheel. Instead of using the base `Link` component you should use the [`NavLink`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link) component. It applies an `"active"` class by default.

Example:

```
import { NavLink, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
...

const anchors = [
  {
    id: "topics",
    icon: <InfoCircleFill />,
    text: "topics",
    link: "/"
  },
  {
    id: "employees",
    icon: <PersonLinesFill />,
    text: "employees",
    link: "employees"
  },
  {
    id: "dashboard",
    icon: <BarChartFill />,
    text: "dashboard",
    link: "dashboard"
  },
  {
    id: "user-entry",
    icon: <PersonPlusFill />,
    text: "user",
    link: "user"
  }
];

const SideBar = () => (
  <nav>
    {anchors.map((anchor) => (
      <NavLink
        to={anchor.link}
        key={anchor.id}
        className="list-group-item border-0 d-inline-block text-truncate mb-3"
        data-bs-parent="#sidebar"
        end
      >
        {anchor.icon}
        <span className="ms-2">{anchor.text}</span>
      </NavLink>
    ))}
    <Outlet />
  </nav>
);
```

[image: Edit how-to-get-the-current-path-using-react-router-dom]

If you needed to customize the classname though, i.e. `"myCustomActiveClassName"`, then use the callback function syntax. An `isActive` prop is passed to the callback.

Example:

```js
className={({ isActive }) => [
  "list-group-item border-0 d-inline-block text-truncate mb-3",
  isActive ? "myCustomActiveClassName" : null
]
  .filter(Boolean)
  .join(" ")
}
```